# How do I set up mail adapter on Bitnami parse server?

Tags: android, amazon-ec2, parse-server, mailgun, bitnami

I'm new to bitnami so setting up the email adapter is proving quite difficult for my android app, any assistance would be appreciated. My goal is to send a password reset to a user after they enter their email address on my app.

**What Have I done so far**

- Created a custom domain and setting up mailgun, acquiring the API key
- Set up AWS and once Bitnami was up and running connected Parse to my app
- I made sure parse-server-simple-mailgun-adapter was installed
- Since app folder and server.js file does not exist anymore when searching through previous forums I placed the below code into this index.js file - /opt/bitnami/parse/node_modules/parse-server/lib/index.js

I taken this code from the following entry https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server

The code currently looks like this in my index.js file:

```
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
Object.defineProperty(exports, "S3Adapter", {
  enumerable: true,
  get: function () {
    return _s3FilesAdapter.default;
  }
});
Object.defineProperty(exports, "FileSystemAdapter", {
  enumerable: true,
  get: function () {
    return _fsFilesAdapter.default;
  }
});
Object.defineProperty(exports, "InMemoryCacheAdapter", {
  enumerable: true,
  get: function () {
    return _InMemoryCacheAdapter.default;
  }
});
Object.defineProperty(exports, "NullCacheAdapter", {
  enumerable: true,
  get: function () {
    return _NullCacheAdapter.default;
  }
});
Object.defineProperty(exports, "RedisCacheAdapter", {
  enumerable: true,
  get: function () {
    return _RedisCacheAdapter.default;
  }
});
Object.defineProperty(exports, "LRUCacheAdapter", {
  enumerable: true,
  get: function () {
    return _LRUCache.default;
  }
});
Object.defineProperty(exports, "PushWorker", {
  enumerable: true,
  get: function () {
    return _PushWorker.PushWorker;
  }
});
Object.defineProperty(exports, "ParseGraphQLServer", {
  enumerable: true,
  get: function () {
    return _ParseGraphQLServer.ParseGraphQLServer;
  }
});
exports.TestUtils = exports.ParseServer = exports.GCSAdapter = exports.default = void 

var _ParseServer2 = _interopRequireDefault(require("./ParseServer"));

var _s3FilesAdapter = _interopRequireDefault(require("@parse/s3-files-adapter"));

var _fsFilesAdapter = _interopRequireDefault(require("@parse/fs-files-adapter"));

var _InMemoryCacheAdapter = _interopRequireDefault(require("./Adapters/Cache/InMemoryC

var _NullCacheAdapter = _interopRequireDefault(require("./Adapters/Cache/NullCacheAdap

var _RedisCacheAdapter = _interopRequireDefault(require("./Adapters/Cache/RedisCacheAd

var _LRUCache = _interopRequireDefault(require("./Adapters/Cache/LRUCache.js"));

var TestUtils = _interopRequireWildcard(require("./TestUtils"));

exports.TestUtils = TestUtils;

var _deprecated = require("./deprecated");

var _logger = require("./logger");

var _PushWorker = require("./Push/PushWorker");

var _Options = require("./Options");

var _ParseGraphQLServer = require("./GraphQL/ParseGraphQLServer");

var server = ParseServer({
        ...otherOptions,
        // Enable email verification
verifyUserEmails: true,
// if `verifyUserEmails` is `true` and
        // //     if `emailVerifyTokenValidityDuration` is `undefined` then
        // //        email verify token never expires
        // //     else
        // //        email verify token expires after `emailVerifyTokenValidityDuration`
        // //
        // // `emailVerifyTokenValidityDuration` defaults to `undefined`
// email verify token below expires in 2 hours (= 2 * 60 * 60 == 7200 seconds)
        // emailVerifyTokenValidityDuration: 2 * 60 * 60, // in seconds (2 hours = 7200 seconds)

// set preventLoginWithUnverifiedEmail to false to allow user to login without verifying their email
        // // set preventLoginWithUnverifiedEmail to true to prevent user from login if their email is not verified
preventLoginWithUnverifiedEmail: false, // defaults to false

// The public URL of your app.
        // // This will appear in the link that is used to verify email addresses and reset passwords.
        // // Set the mount path as it is in serverURL
publicServerURL: 'https://xxxxxxxx/xxxxx/',
// Your apps name. This will appear in the subject and body of the emails that are sent.
appName: 'parse-server',
// The email adapter
emailAdapter: {
          module: '@parse/simple-mailgun-adapter',
          options: {
        // The address that your emails come from
          fromAddress: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
         // Your domain from mailgun.com
        domain: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
         // Your API key from mailgun.com
          apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  }
},

// account lockout policy setting (OPTIONAL) - defaults to undefined
        // // if the account lockout policy is set and there are more than `threshold` number of failed login attempts 
r code `Parse.Error.OBJECT_NOT_FOUND` with error message `Your account is locked due to multiple failed login attempts.
ute(s)`. After `duration` minutes of no login attempts, the application will allow the user to try login again.
accountLockout: {
        duration: 5, // duration policy setting determines the number of minutes that a locked-out account remains locked out before automatically becom
nlocked. Set it to a value greater than 0 and less than 100000.
          threshold: 3, // threshold policy setting determines the number of failed sign-in attempts that will cause a user account to be locked. Set it
n integer value greater than 0 and less than 1000.
},

// optional settings to enforce password policies
passwordPolicy: {
  // Two optional settings to enforce strong passwords. Either one or both can be specified.
        //   // If both are specified, both checks must pass to accept the password
        //     // 1. a RegExp object or a regex string representing the pattern to enforce
validatorPattern: /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.{8,})/, // enforce password with at least 8 char with at least 1 lower case, 1 upper case and 1
t
          // 2. a callback function to be invoked to validate the password
  validatorCallback: (password) => { return validatePassword(password) },
          doNotAllowUsername: true, // optional setting to disallow username in passwords
  maxPasswordAge: 90, // optional setting in days for password expiry. Login fails if user does not reset the password within this period after signup/l
eset.
maxPasswordHistory: 5, // optional setting to prevent reuse of previous n passwords. Maximum value that can be specified is 20. Not specifying it or spe
ng 0 will not enforce history.
          //optional setting to set a validity duration for password reset links (in seconds)
resetTokenValidityDuration: 24*60*60, // expire after 24 hours
        }
});


function _getRequireWildcardCache() { if (typeof WeakMap !== "function") return null; var cache = new WeakMap(); _getRequireWildcardCache = function () { ret
urn cache; }; return cache; }

function _interopRequireWildcard(obj) { if (obj && obj.__esModule) { return obj; } if (obj === null || typeof obj !== "object" && typeof obj !== "function") 
{ return { default: obj }; } var cache = _getRequireWildcardCache(); if (cache && cache.has(obj)) { return cache.get(obj); } var newObj = {}; var hasProperty
Descriptor = Object.defineProperty && Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor; for (var key in obj) { if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) { var desc 
= hasPropertyDescriptor ? Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, key) : null; if (desc && (desc.get || desc.set)) { Object.defineProperty(newObj, key, desc); }
 else { newObj[key] = obj[key]; } } } newObj.default = obj; if (cache) { cache.set(obj, newObj); } return newObj; }

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

// Factory function
const _ParseServer = function (options) {
  const server = new _ParseServer2.default(options);
  return server.app;
}; // Mount the create liveQueryServer


exports.ParseServer = _ParseServer;
_ParseServer.createLiveQueryServer = _ParseServer2.default.createLiveQueryServer;
_ParseServer.start = _ParseServer2.default.start;
const GCSAdapter = (0, _deprecated.useExternal)('GCSAdapter', '@parse/gcs-files-adapter');
exports.GCSAdapter = GCSAdapter;
Object.defineProperty(module.exports, 'logger', {
  get: _logger.getLogger
});
var _default = _ParseServer2.default;
exports.default = _default;
```

My config.json file looks like this(Config file located /opt/bitnami/parse) :

```
{
  "appId": "myapp",
  "masterKey": "NTxxxxxxmm",
  "appName": "parse-server",
  "mountPath": "/parse",
  "port": "1337",
  "host": "0.0.0.0",
  "serverURL": "http://3.1xxxxx5/parse/",
  "databaseURI": "mongodb://bn_parse:TFyNVz7Y45@127.xxxxx:27xx7/bitnami_parse"
}
```

When I run my app with the following code:

```
ParseUser.requestPasswordResetInBackground("myemail@gmail.com",
                    new RequestPasswordResetCallback() {
                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                            if (e == null) {
                                // An email was successfully sent with reset instructions.
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Password Reset email has been sent to this email address",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } else {
                                // Something went wrong. Look at the ParseException to see what's up.
                                Log.i("Error", "Password Reset Error", e);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Saving user failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

I get the following Error message in the logs:

```
2020-06-13 23:13:05.704 15647-15647/com.example.Fitness I/Error: Password Reset Error
    com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: bad json response
        at com.parse.ParseRequest.newTemporaryException(ParseRequest.java:290)
        at com.parse.ParseRESTCommand.onResponseAsync(ParseRESTCommand.java:308)
        at com.parse.ParseRESTUserCommand.onResponseAsync(ParseRESTUserCommand.java:126)
        at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:137)
        at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:133)
        at bolts.Task$15.run(Task.java:917)
        at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
        at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:908)
        at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:715)
        at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:726)
        at bolts.Task$13.then(Task.java:818)
        at bolts.Task$13.then(Task.java:806)
        at bolts.Task$15.run(Task.java:917)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
        at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
        at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:163)
        at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:176)
        at com.parse.ParseRESTCommand.onResponseAsync(ParseRESTCommand.java:298)
        at com.parse.ParseRESTUserCommand.onResponseAsync(ParseRESTUserCommand.java:126) 
        at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:137) 
        at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:133) 
        at bolts.Task$15.run(Task.java:917) 
        at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105) 
        at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:908) 
        at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:715) 
        at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:726) 
        at bolts.Task$13.then(Task.java:818) 
        at bolts.Task$13.then(Task.java:806) 
        at bolts.Task$15.run(Task.java:917) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
2020-06-13 23:13:05.754 1441-1441/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 360448
```

It looks like the email address which is a string cannot be converted to a JSON object, I've checked and made sure that my server URL has a "/" at the end of the URL. I also added 'com.parse:parse-android:1.12.0' into my gradle to see if that would fix it but the issue is still occurring.

If I've added these entries in the wrong index.js file or need to format the file can someone let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The code you copied and pasted is unfortunately rather difficult to follow, but the error

> Caused by: org.json.JSONException: Value

indicates that the URL your Android app is reaching is not returning JSON data. Your Android code is either not hitting the proper URL to invoke the function, or your server is misconfigured and is returning HTML (probably an error page or a 404) to the Android app. Unless you've tested and verified that you can successfully invoke a basic function that returns JSON, I'd suggest removing all the email-related code and working on that first, before trying to put that back in.